# OK To Use This Male/Female Jack Combo For 24 Volt DC?

Tags: motor, dc, dc-motor, 24v

I'm using 24 volt DC motors along with 12 volt solenoid actuators for a installation piece.  For ease of install and maintenance, I want to wire each motor with a barrel jack like the one below:

[https://www.amazon.com/43x2pcs-Connectors-Security-Lighting-MILAPEAK/dp/B072BXB2Y8/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=male+female+pigtail+dc+jack&qid=1564592392&s=gateway&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072BXB2Y8)

The wire is 18 gauge which works great for me but I'm a bit concerned about the title apparently giving these a 12V 5A rating.

I expect each motor to draw only a few amps.  The loads are not too extreme, only a few pounds, and the motors are definitely able to handle the load.

I'm more concerned about the jacks being able to handle 24 volts.  Although, I may be overthinking this a bit.

Will these jacks be ok or are there other jacks I should use?

Note, I did find screw terminal barrel jack adapters but I like the ones in the link I posted since the jack is a bit smaller which would make routing my wires through the cable chase channels easier.

Answer (score 1):

Only the manufacturer knows **why** these connectors are rated for 12V usage. If you use them at 24V you are on your own. The connectors might fail immediately or might never give you any trouble. If they fail they could fail into a safe mode, simply cutting off the flow of current, or they could catch fire.

We can give you an **opinion** about using the connectors outside of their specified operating range, but we really don't like to rely on opinions and assumptions as engineers.